Heteroskedasticity Robust Standard Errors Interpretation Problem
I am performing a multiple linear regression analysis for my thesis. I have heteroskedasticity problem in my dataset. I performed white test and it shows heteroscedasticity. To remove heteroskedasticity, I tried log transformation of my regression analysis and again performed white test but the log transformed regression white test also shows heteroskedasticity. Then I performed heteroskedasticity robust standard errors in Rstudio of the log transformed data. But I am having problem understanding and interpreting the result. My question is how would I know that the heteroskedasticity problem is removed by observing robust standard errors? I am sharing my codes and outcomes in the next section.
Could anyone please help me by interpreting my result to understand that heteroskedasticity is removed?
Regression model:
regression <- lm(GDPG ~ FDI + LINR + TR + INFR + EXR, data = thesisdataset)
summary(regression)
Outcome:
enter image description here
White test:
white_test <- bptest(regression)
print(white_test)
Outcome:
studentized Breusch-Pagan test
data:  regression
BP = 13.607, df = 5, p-value = 0.01831
Log linera model:
regression_log <- lm(log(GDPG) ~ FDI + LINR + TR + INFR + EXR, data = thesisdataset)
summary(regression_log)
Outcome:
enter image description here
White test log model:
white_test_log <- bptest(regression_log)
print(white_test_log)
Outcome:
studentized Breusch-Pagan test
data:  regression_log
BP = 13.843, df = 5, p-value = 0.01664
Heteroskedasticity Robust Standard Errors:
robust_se <- coeftest(regression_log, vcov = vcovHC(regression_log, type = "HC0"))
print(robust_se)
Outcome:
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
